# Adding XML Elements With The Same Name In PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, vmware

I have a template for adding firewall rules that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rule disabled="false" logged="false">
    <name></name>
    <action>allow</action>
    <notes></notes>
    <appliedToList>
        <appliedTo>
            <value></value>
        </appliedTo>
    </appliedToList>
    <sectionId></sectionId>
    <sources excluded="true">
        <source>
            <value></value>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <destinations excluded="false">
        <destination>
            <value></value>
        </destination>
    </destinations>
    <services>
        <service>
            <value></value>
        </service>
    </services>
</rule>
```

It works fine as long as we require only one service, source or destination. What I would like to be able to do is create new child nodes in PowerShell if there are, for example, multiple destinations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rule disabled="false" logged="false">
    <destinations excluded="false">
        <destination>
            <value></value>
        </destination>
        <destination>
            <value></value>
        </destination>
    </destinations>
</rule>
```

I tried following the help [here.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/07/29/how-to-add-data-to-an-xml-file-using-windows-powershell/)

```
$newL3Rule = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content C:\nsx-xml\new-layer3rule.xml)
$new = $newL3Rule.rule.destinations.destination.Clone()
$newL3Rule.DocumentElement.AppendChild($new)
```

But the new destination appears under rule rather than destinations. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close, you just have to use

```
$newL3Rule.DocumentElement.destinations.AppendChild($new)
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rule disabled="false" logged="false">
    <name></name>
    <action>allow</action>
    <notes></notes>
    <appliedToList>
        <appliedTo>
            <value></value>
        </appliedTo>
    </appliedToList>
    <sectionId></sectionId>
    <sources excluded="true">
        <source>
            <value></value>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <destinations excluded="false">
        <destination>
            <value></value>
        </destination>
        <destination>
            <value></value>
        </destination>
    </destinations>
    <services>
        <service>
            <value></value>
        </service>
    </services>
</rule>
```

---

**Explanation**: what you did was adding child item to the top level of XML. If you want to append child to `destinations` you have to specify that you want to add it there.

Comment: No worries, we all were learning at some point of time, it's good to ask if you tried and got stuck. Please remember to mark answer as accepted if it helped you to resolve your problem! See [someone answers article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info.